# bash - combine while read with grep and cut

Tags: bash

I want to modify my existing bash script. This is how it looks now:

```
#! /bin/bash    
SAMPLE = myfile.txt

while read SAMPLE
do
    name = $SAMPLE
    # some other code
done < $SAMPLE
```

In this case 'myfile'.txt consists only of one column, with all the info I need.

Now I want to modify this script because 'myfile.txt' contains now more columns and more lines than I need.

```
grep 'TEST' myfile.txt | cut -d "," -f 1
```

gives me the values I need. But how can I integrate this into my bash script?

Comment: Do you want to check each line if that has test or not? And then perform some action on it? Could you please confirm on same.

Comment: Just as a style note: It's often not a good idea, to use the same name for two different variables. In your script you use `SAMPLE` both for the input file name and for the value that is read from the file. Better give them different names (like in my answer below).

Comment: Your code is incorrect, assignments in `bash` don't take spaces on either side of `=`

Comment: https://shellcheck.net try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the output of any command into a `while read` loop.

Try this:

```
#! /bin/bash    
INPUT=myfile.txt

grep 'TEST' $INPUT | 
cut -d "," -f 1 | 
while read SAMPLE
do
    name=$SAMPLE
    # some other code
done
```

Comment: Tip: if you place `|` on the end of the line, you don't need trailing '\'.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @KamilCuk! I changed the code accordingly.

Comment: The problem with the pipe is, that it creates a sub-shell. This means, that the code in the body of the `while` loop has no access to the environment of the script. You can not change any variables outside the loop. This is often not desired.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the input field separator (IFS), which tells `read` where to split the input line. Then you tell `read` to read two fields: the one you need and one you do not care about.

```
#! /bin/bash    
SAMPLE=myfile.txt

while IFS=, read SAMPLE dontcare
do
    name="$SAMPLE"
    # some other code
done < <(grep TEST "$SAMPLE")
```

By the way: whenever you use `read`, you should consider to use the option `-r`.

Comment: I only want to scan lines that contain 'TEST'. That's why I need the grep

Comment: @user1987607 I added your "TEST" requirement.